# Opencart categories links from main page

Tags: php, html, opencart

I would like to know how do I create my main categories on my homepage in **Opencart** to make 3 categories in a row each of which followed by it's subcategories like this:
[image: Scheme]
Sorry for my drawing skills. So there are going to be a clicable picture for each category and subcategory. However

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=59'); ?">pic</a>
```

does not work for me. It says "Access forbidden", so
**Is there any other way to make this?** because as soon as I will be able to make a simple working link, I would be able to deal with the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generally avoid calling methods in the view (tpl).  I would recommend defining it first in the relevant controller.  In any event, your link should work but you have a misplaced quotation mark and you did not close you opening anchor tag.  I should look like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=59'); ?>">pic</a>
```

**UPDATE:**

As you have explained that you are adding this as html from an extension you cannot call a php function from there so you'll need to specify the actual link, which in this case would be:

```
<a href="/index.php?route=product/category&path=59">pic</a>
```

or based on the comment you posted

```
<a href="/shop/index.php?route=product/category&path=59">pic</a>
```

Comment: It still says access forbidden. I call this from a HTML code module, even not from the tpl. As soon as I click a link it shows **http://localhost/shop/%3C?php%20echo%20$this-%3Eurl-%3Elink(%27product/category%27,%20%27path=59%27);%20?%3E** and says access forbidden

Comment: You can't call php from a module rendering html like that since it's php which is rendering it to begin with.  In that case you need to add the actual link.  I'm updating my answer.